# How to find if jre or jdk is installed in Mac and if not install jre using shell script

Tags: java, macos, shell, installation

Before I install a Java application on any client machine (Mac OSX >10.5), I would like to first see if either JDK or JRE is installed already in the machine. If JRE/JDK is not present, I want to install JRE in that machine and then proceed with the actual application installation.

Was wondering how to write a shell script to find if Java is already installed in the client machine, and conditionally proceed with rest of the installation. Any pointers to built-in tools/ sample code will help.

Answer (score -1):

Try running this command from shell script, result can be used to do further application installation.

```
if [ `java -version | grep -q "java version"` ]; then
  echo "Java installed"
fi
```

Comment: Thank you! May I also know how to find where JRE/JDK is installed in the client system?

Comment: Different ways to check java installation path on different OS clients.

Comment: Specifically on Mac OSX > 10.5

Comment: You could try `printenv | grep JAVA_HOME` or `echo $(/usr/libexec/java_home)` (OS X) if you have access to client terminal.